# iOS -- UILabel with UITextAlignmentLeft clips an integral sign ∫ if it is the first character of its text

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

The following is basically my entire project to illustrate the problem:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    UILabel *integralLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(30, 60, 200, 150)];
    integralLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:100];
    [window addSubview:integralLabel];
    integralLabel.text = @"∫∫∫";
    integralLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    integralLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The leftmost integral sign in the label is clipped.

Is there a clean way to fix this?  The contents of my labels will change frequently in response to all sorts of things, so I don't want to do something hackish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a space at the beginning if the text begins with the integral sign:

```
if ([[integralLabel.text substringToIndex:1]isEqualToString:@"∫"])
{
    integralLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", integralLabel.text];
}
```

**EDIT**

To distinguish between this space and other spaces in the label, you can use different Unicode values for spaces (full list here: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html)

```
@"\u205F%@"
```

etc...

**EDIT 2**

You can also subclass UILabel by overriding `drawTextInRect:`.

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (![[self.text substringToIndex:1]isEqualToString:@"∫"])
    {
        [super drawTextInRect:rect];
    }
    else
    {
        CGRect paddingLeftRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + 25.0, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
        [super drawTextInRect:paddingLeftRect];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's the hack I'm hoping to avoid . . . the problem is that we are dealing with a lot of different labels, and their text could change frequently, and now we have to keep track of whether the space is a "real" space inserted by the user, or a "virtual" space inserted for formatting, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: See my edit. There are different space "types" to distinguish between others that may in your label.

Comment: See Edit 2. I subclassed UILabel for you.

Comment: The check mark is for the subclass.  Basically, he overrode the drawTextInRect method to move the rectangle to the right.

Comment: I edited my subclass. Please re-download. The update checks if the first character is the integral sign and then adjusts the position.

Comment: Could you paste here the contents of that -drawTextInRect?  zip file is no longer available.

Comment: @croald Code is there now. It's just a simple padding adjustment. However, you may want to do something more involved, like create a custom UIView with different labels - e.g. one for the symbol and another for the expression.